# Problem finding roots of 3d degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Hi I need to find the root of a $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial in the form of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ but problem is, I cannot use the briot-rufini or horner method (roots are not integers?) because they don't work in this case, since the divisors of the variable of least exponent are not solutions to the equation.

I also cannot put in evidence any part of the equation in a similar way to:
$X^2(x+z)+X(x+z)$
since it does not exist a common part to put in evidence, and therefore I cannot simplify it.

Is there a SURE method to solve ANY $3^{rd}$ degree equation?

Comment: You may be happy (or not) to hear about [Cardano's method](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula)

Comment: Hi Hagen, it won't work. It needs a cubic function of type $x^3+px+q=0$, and mine of type  $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. (Or I cannot reduce it to that form) Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Hi Hagen. Sorry you are absolutely right. I found this:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cubic_equation